# Setup Heroku Scheduler job to email all users (Meteor/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, meteor, cron

Does anyone know if it's possible to make a Heroku Scheduler job that would send an email to all of my users once per day? I'm using Meteor and MongoDB.

I can see that the Heroku Scheduler can run a command such as "node somefile.js" but I can't seem to figure out how to make a connection to the mongodb in a file like this. Can I somehow tap into the DB without involving Meteor in this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find anything useful since then?

Comment: I have the same requirement. Does this work for you? https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron

Comment: @Alveoli That works but if you are using free dyno, it will sleep after a while and the cron job will fire off during sleep.

Comment: @Yulong I couldn't figure out how to do it with heroku scheduler so I ended up coding something using Meteor's "setInterval" and the email package.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a package to do so: [synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron). Basically, you need to setup a method in which use the package to fire a recurring job.

The package website also has a sample code:

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 2 hours');
  },
  job: function() {
    var numbersCrunched = CrushSomeNumbers();
    return numbersCrunched;
  }
});
```

Here you just need to replace the code in the job function to send out the email.

The job supports schedules like "every 5 minutes", "at 5:00pm", etc. The package relies on the text parser in Later.js to parse the schedule. You can refer to the [Later.js doc](http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Two different options.

The first is to use Heroku's scheduler,

In which you create a text file in your bin directory:

```
#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node
var test = require('./jobToDo') //put your job in this file (jobToDo.js)
```

Now you don't have to put the job in another .js file, but it makes it easier to work with, rather than coding in a plain text file. (put again that is up to you)

The first line `#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node` may be different for you depending on how your configuration is set up, depending on your OS and node/npm set up.

The second option is a cron style library. This will allow you to decide when you want your code to run.

This is pretty easy, and for me the preferred method.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var fn = function(){
   // Do Something
}
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: "00 00 02 * * 1-5",
  onTick: fn,
  start: true,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
```

You can look at documentation [on github](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)